# Stub ActiveRecord::Relation with ActiveRecord objects

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec, mocking, relation

I'm not testing a Rails app. Just getting that out of the way.

I'm testing a library that connects to a relatively active server, restricting records by timestamp. These returned records change as time goes on, making testing other restrictions more complicated. I need to stub out the `ActiveRecord::where` method to return my own custom relation with objects I create to meet the criteria I need.

Something like

```
relation = double(ActiveRecord::Relation)
relation.stub(:[]).and_return( [MyClass.new(...), MyClass.new(...), ...] )
MyClass.stub(:where).and_return( relation )
```

is what I'd like, but that doesn't work. I need it to be an `ActiveRecord::Relation` because I need to be able to call `ActiveRecord::where` and `ActiveRecord::select` on the object in the code.

---

**Edit 2014-01-28**

In lib/call.rb

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def sales start_time, end_time
      restricted_records = records(start_time, end_time, :agent_id)
      #other code
    end

    #other methods

    private

      def records start_time, end_time, *select
        # I'm leaving in commented code so you can see why I want the ActiveRecord::Relation object, not an Array
        calls = Call.where("ts BETWEEN '#{start_time}' AND '#{end_time}'") #.select(select)
        raise calls.inspect
          #.to_a.map(&:serializable_hash).map {|record| symbolize(record)}
      end
  end
end
```

In spec/call_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'call.rb'

describe Call do
  let(:period_start) { Time.now - 60 }
  let(:period_end) { Time.now }

  describe "::sales" do
    before do
      relation = Call.all
      relation.stub(:[]).and_return( [Call.new(queue: "12345")] )
      Call.stub(:where).and_return( relation )
    end

    subject { Call.sales(period_start, period_end) }

    it "restricts results to my custom object" do
      subject
    end
  end
end
```

Output from test:

```
RuntimeError:
  #<ActiveRecord::Relation [ #an array containing all the actual Call records, not my object ]>
```

Answer (score 6):

`ActiveRecord::Relation` is a class and `:[]` is an instance method of that class. You're stubbing a method of the class itself, so it's not going to be invoked by any of the Rails code.

If you want `MyClass.where` to return a relation with just the `:[]` stubbed, you'll have to create a Relation instance first, as in:

```
relation = MyClass.all
relation.stub(:[]).and_return( [MyClass.new(...), MyClass.new(...), ...] )
MyClass.stub(:where).and_return( relation )
```

However, note that in order to get to your returned array in this context, you'll need to do:

```
MyClass.where("ignored parameters")["ignored parameters"]
```

Further, if you subsequently call `where` on `relation`, you'll return a *new* instance of `Relation` which will no longer be stubbed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this just returns the initial `MyClass.all` relation instead of my stubbed response. Should I be stubbing a different method?

Comment: When you say "this" just returns the initial `MyClass.all`, what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, when my tests run, calling `MyClass.where(args args args)` it's returning the collection initially returned from `MyClass.all`, not the stubbed collection you wrote on line 2. Is `:[]` the right method?

Comment: It returns the `MyClass.all` relation with the `:[]` method stubbed, which is what your question said it wanted to do. If you send the `:[]` method to that object (i.e. as my answer said you needed to do), you'll get the array you indicated. As to whether this is the "right" method to stub, I can't answer that for you as I don't know all the different ways in which you want the Relation to function.

Comment: Hmm. Well that is not how this code is behaving for me. I copied the lines into my editor, changed to my class name and ran the tests. It's returning all the records, not my restricted collection.

Comment: Please post the code you're running and the results you're getting.

Comment: Ok, you're not calling the `[]` method on the `where` result, so you're stub isn't taking effect. If you said `subject['whatever']` in your spec, you'd get the custom array back. If you want `where` itself to return the custom array, you can do that, but then it won't be a relation - it will be an array.

Comment: Ok. I was mainly curious if this was even possible, and it seems to not be (according to what you just said). Looks like I'll have to suck it up and create a test database after all. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

### Update 2022

The previous upvoted answer is wholly incorrect since does not work with indexing, `.to_a`, `.first`, `.last`, `.any?`, `.none?`, and most other methods.

Instead, you can mock the records contained within a relation by stubbing its `records` method.

```rb
custom_records = ["a", "b", "c"]

relation = Model.all
relation.stub(:records).and_return(custom_records)

allow(Model).to receive(:where).and_return(relation)

# Later ...

records = Model.where('1 + 1 = 2') # content of the query doesn't matter, .where is mocked
records.first # => "a"
records.last # => "c"
records.to_a # => ["a", "b", "c"]
records.any? { |x| x == "b" } # => true
```

Most of the methods will work, but there are a few exceptions that will need to be stubbed separately.

- `.count` - directly invokes a `SELECT COUNT(*)` SQL query, which bypasses our `records` mock. Fix:

  ```rb
  relation.stub(:count).and_return(custom_records.count)
  ```
- `.exists?` - directly invokes another SQL query, again bypassing our `records` mock. Fix:

  ```rb
  relation.stub(:exists?).and_return(custom_records.present?)
  ```
- others - There are probably other methods that you might need to stub (depending on if your code uses those methods), you can stub each method on an as-needed basis.

Furthermore you can mock the return value of a `has_many` relation (which was my actual use case when googling this question) by doing

```rb
allow(record).to receive(:related_records).and_wrap_original do |original, *args, &block|
  relation = original.call(*args, &block)
  relation.stub(:records).and_return(my_custom_array_of_related_records)
  relation
end
```